# Session expired or invalidated in Chrome when using alias

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, session, icefaces

I have a web application built using IceFaces 1.8.2 deployed on WebSphere 6.

1. When I try to access it by using server IP address  or host-name  (for example by calling 10.250.46.80:8080/myApplication or host.domain.com:8080/myApplication), everything works OK.
2. When I try to access it by alias (example www.myapplication.com) the application loads the welcome page, redirects to jspx page with no trouble but then I see it continues loading something for few seconds and than I get an http error 500 saying:

```
Error Message: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: User session has expired or it was invalidated.
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: Persistent Faces Servlet
Error Stack:
java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Problem in renderResponse: User session has expired or it was invalidated.
     at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:153)
     at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:52)
...
...
     at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:49)
     at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
     at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:78)
     at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:150)
     ... 44 more
```

I tried to turn on the synchronous update and the application doesn't crash anymore but I noticed none of the Ajax functionality is working like ValueChange listeners for example. When I change value in a dropdown list (partial submit), browser starts loading something and then I get the error 500 again.

This only happens when using Google Chrome as the browser. It doesn't happen in IE, Opera, Firefox or Safari.

I tried to manually invoke an Ajax request for send-recieve-updates in Chrome console but the response was <session-expired/> In Firefox I got normal content.

I tried random stuff like align headers but since Chrome prevents modification of most headers I can't really try to align them with Firefox's ones to test it.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: So we finally found the problem. When using aliases www.myapplication.com the requests are redirected to a random node like nodeXX.domain.com:/myApplication where the welcome page creates a new session and redirects the a proper jspx page.

Comment: We didnt have a favicon.ico on the jspx page so Chrome inserted a default link for favicon.ico with src = www.myapplication.com/favicon.ico or something similar which caused a redirect since an alias was used again and the circle started again. You gotta love the intelligent browsers.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using alias (I do not know the exact naming: url rewriting/forwarding? virtual host/proxy pass?) that causes a forward/redirect make sure that the browser does not insert something by default in your page that includes the alias again or you may end up in an infinite loop.

Solution to my case was that I inserted my own favicon image so Chrome does not insert a default one.